# ¿Cómo funciona la regla de CSS input:valid+<clase>?

Tags: css, html5, css3

Estoy creando un captcha y encontré uno muy interesante con una funcionalidad muy particular y que no sé cómo está funcionando detrás ya que es una función que me ayudaría mucho a la hora de realizar validaciones interactivas en lugar de hacerlo con javascript.

El captcha tiene el input para escribir el captcha, al escribir en él, el botón de check se visualiza (yo le metí unas transiciones para que se viera un poco más animado).

Pero no entiendo cómo puedo acceder desde un elemento hacia otro elemento hermano.

```css
.container-captcha .input-area .check-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: -50%;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translate(130%, 50%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.container-captcha .input-area input:valid+.check-btn {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    transform: translate(0%, 50%) !important;
    pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <form action="#" class="input-area">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter captcha" maxlength="6" spellcheck="false" required>
        <button class="check-btn">Check</button>
    </form>
    <div class="status-text"></div>
</div>
```

El botón inicialmente no se ve, y esa regla de `valid+.check-btn` no la entiendo; si alguien pudiese poner un ejemplo similar sería genial, como por ejemplo un input que al escribir en él muestre un label con un texto debajo o arriba (que estando el input vacío, este texto no se vea).

Comment: se le conoce como selector adyancente tecnicamente lo que hace es afectar al elemento hermano siguiente:  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator